# Ubuntu standard folders changed name (name1, name10, name4 etc)

Tags: 18.04, directory

I don't know what happened, but after start I realized the folders have changed name, then ones that usually were:

Music, Pictures, Videos, etc

Became:

name1, name10, name14 etc

When I open folder explorer and click on Documents, for example, I see the following error message:

> Oops, something went wrong.
>
> Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.

Just Downloads still the same name, how can I solve this?

Comment: Most folks can, with a bit of detective work, simply rename each directory back to it's old name. Are you saying this is not possible?

Comment: No, it's possible, to solve that I renamed the folders, however I wanted to know if that is some common error, to avoid that happening again and make me lost some files or something like that.

Comment: Definitely not common.